# Cannot create a new Theme

Tags: theme, registration

I followed the devdocs below link to create theme:

> http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

But after I added the **`registration.php`**, the Magento admin returns error.

Here is my **`registration.php`**, **file structure** and **`Composer.json`**

[image]

Would you let me know what my error is ?

Comment: `Magento admin returns error.` please edit your quetion with the error

Comment: I also noticed that you're working with the docs for Magento 2.0. Please make sure you are reading the docs for your version and consider upgrade to Magento 2.2.X because 2.0 is outdated